# How to query tables with for loop in R?

Tags: sql, r, database

I have a vector with table names:

```
table_names <- c("table1", "table2", "table3", "table4")
```

I want to query all this tables with limit 100 using for loop like this:

```
for (val in table_names){
   my_query = pastge0("SELECT * FROM", val, " LIMIT 100")
   dbGetQuery(con, my_query)
```

As you see this looping creates 4 querys and 4 tables. However I want those tables to be named. How to get these for tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's often best to use `lapply` and keep the frames in a `list` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/3358227):

```r
allfour <- lapply(setNames(paste("select * from", table_names, "limit 100"),
                           table_names),
                  DBI::dbGetQuery, conn = con)
```

If you don't want them in a `list`, then you can assign them to an environment with `list2env`, such as

```r
list2env(allfour, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: thanks, but i need four tables in my Environment in R, not nested list

Comment: is it possible to give those tables according names from table_names?

Comment: @french_fries Think twice before looking at r2evans' edit. Usually keeping things in a list is the better choice: You avoid cluttering your namespace, you can easily access every table within the list and you keep all of the `lapply`-etc goodness.